# python setting value to list elements

Tags: list, python-2.7, indexing

Basically what I'm trying to do is, create a nestled list and set a value of one of its element as a function of other elements in the list.

```
>>> a = [[1]*5]*5
>>> a
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> a[2][2] = a[0][2] + a[2][1]
>>> a
[[1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]]
>>> a[3][2]   
2
>>> a[4][2]
2
>>> a[4][4]
1
```

I just set the value of a[2][2] but the same value got set to every element in the 3rd column. What is going on exactly and how can I get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that `a` ends up containing five references to the same sublist. When you change one sublist, they all change.

To see this, apply [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) to each of the sublists:

```
>>> map(id, a)
[8189352, 8189352, 8189352, 8189352, 8189352]
```

As you can see, they all have the same ID, meaning they are the same object.

To fix, replace

```
a = [[1]*5]*5
```

with

```
a = [[1]*5 for _ in range(5)]
```

Now the sublists are independent objects:

```
>>> map(id, a)
[21086256, 18525680, 18524720, 19331112, 18431472]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your list `a` contains five references to the same list.  You need to do something like this:

```
a = []
for _ in range(5):
    a += [[1] * 5]
```